# map reduce function return id instead of count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoengine

I m applying map reduce function but facing an issue. In case of one record it returns the id instead of count = 1.

```
    map_func = """function () {
        emit(this.school_id, this.student_id);
    }"""
    reduce_func = """
        function (k, values) {               
                values.length;
        }
    """
```

if school 100  has only one student then it should return school id 100 , value =1 but in this scenario it return
schoolid = 100 , value = 12 ( 12 is its student id in db ). for other records it works fine.

```
        map_func = """function () {            
         emit({this.school_id, this.student_id},{count:1});
    }"""
    reduce_func = """
        function (k, values) {
            var count =0 ;
            values.forEach(function(v)
            {
               count += v['count'];
            });
            return {count:count};
        }
    """
     map_func2 = """
    function() {
        emit(this['_id']['school_id'], {count: 1});
    }
    """
```

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/unique_items_map_reduce/
i used this example but it uses two maps-reduce function so it took much more time.

Comment: You are mistaking what emit does.  You have to emit the actual final result you want.  school 100 has 1 student so you have to emit 1.  Reduce is where you add all the different emitted values.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may be misunderstanding some of the mechanics of mapReduce.

The emit will get called on every document, but reduce will only be called on keys which have more than one value emitted (because the purpose of the reduce function is to merge or reduce an array of results into one).

You map function is wrong - it needs to emit a key and then a value you want - in this case a count.

Your reduce function needs to reduce these counts (add them) but it has to work correctly even if it gets called multiple times (to re-reduce previously reduced results).

I recommend reading [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) for more details.

Comment: Problem is in case of count = 1 it didt go into the reduce function.

Comment: it doesn't need to go into reduce function - reduce is there to combine multiple results from map functions.  I think you need to review some examples of how it works.  Your reduce should be adding all counts from array it gets to current running count.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to count number of students per school :
map = """emit(this.school_id, 1)"""

reduce = """function (key, values) {var total = 0; for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { total += values[i]; } return total;} """

Comment: There is one more thing user should be distinct against each school. above code works fine but in case of student id = 1 has 3 entries against school 1 then reurn should be school id  = 1 , count  =1

Comment: Thats why i m using map-reudce twice

Comment: i don't know your model but IMHO you have to use an object as id in map something like :  map= """emit( {scid:this.school_id,stid:this.student_id}  , 1)"""

Comment: i have posted all code above in first map make a dict with school id and user id and count 1.

Comment: hi , any solution for the above issue